# How to remove the space to the right of the home icon in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm developing an Android app, and in all of my activities, I have a few pixels of space between the logo and the tabs on the action bar. I've seen similar questions asking how to remove the space on the left side of the home icon on the action bar, but not to the right. How can I remove this space, whether through editing the xml or java? Here's a screenshot: http://filesmelt.com/dl/space13.png

Thanks!

Comment: is that a question or desire?

Comment: Both- I didn't want to repeat the same question in both the title and the body. If you need more information, please let me know!

Comment: whats ur question basically? is that programming question or a trick to perform?

Comment: This is a programming question. I'm asking how to remove the extra space automatically provided to the app's icon, either from xml or java. My apologies for being unclear the first time around- I've edited my question slightly to provide more specific information!

Comment: well, that doesn't clear the thing yet. That will be good to post an image of your problem and indicate the issue